# checking array length in java and if array length is 0 then throw custom exception

Tags: java

I am getting an list while retrieveing it  i am converting it into array and sending it later to the caller function as shown below

```
RokerItemList = brokerInvoice.getLineItems();
            return RokerItemList.toArray(new BrokerInvoiceLineItem[RokerItemList.size()]);
```

now my query is that it can also happens that the list retrieved may not contain any elements and so i want to put a check that while converting it into array
but before that check the converted array length and if it is 0 then throw a custom exception as shown below please advise how to implement this check

```
throw new ASERuntimeException(
                            "  No  items are there in ARRAY  ");
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If all you need to do is guard against null or empty Lists, check the API docs. A typical idiom is "if the list is null or he list is empty, throw".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 if (RokerItemList.isEmpty()) {//check if your list is empty
      //throw exception
 }
 //your conversion logic
```

Comment: no while inspecting i an see null not empty , that is RokerItemList = brokerInvoice.getLineItems(); comes as null

Comment: So why not check something like `if (RokerItemList != null)`?